# angularjs Select with filter to filter out the option that's already selected

Tags: angularjs

My code for select with ng-model is working fine except filter stuff.
Without filter, it's showing duplicated option for the already selected one..
So I am trying to filter out the one already selected in below code.

But it's not working.. Am I doing something wrong? any help please?

```
<select ng-model="result.color">
<option ng-repeat="codes in obj.codes | filter:!result.color" value="{{codes.code}}">{{codes.code}}</option>
<option ng-selected>{{result.color}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: the curly brace at the end of `ng-repeat` is not accompanied with the opening brace.  Are you sure you copy the right code?

Comment: sorry.. My bad when I was copying the code...It's updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-selected` accepts an expression.
This is what I would do:

```
    <option ng-repeat="codes in obj.codes" value="{{codes.code}}" ng-selected="result.color == codes.code">
```

---

== edit ==

another even shorter solution would be to use `ng-options`.

```
<select ng-model="result.color" ng-options="c.code for c in obj.codes"></select>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://plnkr.co/edit/oIysU5

Not sure about the initial value as my fiddle seems working.

Comment: Code is working..That's almost 99% perfect.. The only thing is that initially result.color value is loaded when page is loaded.. Using the answer you suggested it's broken.. Might be some simple way to fix this as well.. any idea?

Comment: @Will, we'd need to see the code. But you might just need to add a $scope.$watch('result.color', function(value) { /*update your other scope vars here */});  it's hard to say without seeing the code though.

Comment: not 100% what I need to do since my code is little complicated.. But accepted answer.. Thanks :)