# Conditionally including select options in angular

Tags: javascript, select, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using an angular select directive.

```
<select
    ng-model="tune.rating"
    ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in dropdowns.rating"
    ng-change="update()" >
    <option ng-if="tune.rating === -1" value="">-- rate tune --</option>
</select>
```

I want the default option to only be included when a rating isn't already given, but the `ng-if` isn't getting applied (both when the controller is loaded and in response to selecting a value)

Is there some way I can get this to work. I can't append the default option conditionally to dropdowns.rating as there are many tunes per page, all of which may be rated or unrated and all of which use the `dropdowns.rating` array

Note: I don't think my question duplicates this one [angularjs Select with filter to filter out the option that's already selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851504/angularjs-select-with-filter-to-filter-out-the-option-thats-already-selected), although they are similar

Comment: Make sure you are using atleast version 1.1.5 for using `ng-if`.

Comment: @CodeHater Good spot. I've upgraded and it now works.

Comment: You can also use ng-hide/ng-show.

Comment: @ZackArgyle - I don't think they work on options as they rely on css which I don't think can be applied to options, angular js or not

Answer (score 0):

Use `$templateCache` and a `for` loop as an alternative:

```js
var app = angular.module('foo', []);

function foo($templateCache)
  {
  var tmpl, lister,
  ProductData = 
    { "odata.metadata": "localhost:51811/odata/$metadata#Products", 
    "value": [
               {
               "ID": 1,
               "Year": 2017, 
               "Name": "Hat", 
               "Price": "15.00", 
               "Category": "Apparel" 
               }
             ]
    };

  lister = function()
   {
    var index, replacement = "";
    for (index in this)
      {
      /* Avoid adding the callback function itself to the array */
      if (/[^\d]/.test(this[index]) === false)
        {
        replacement = replacement.concat("<option>",this[index],"</option>");
        }
      }
    return replacement;
    };
    
  ProductData.value[0].toJSON = lister;
  tmpl = JSON.stringify(ProductData.value[0]);
  
  console.log(tmpl);
    
  $templateCache.put('listContent', tmpl);
  }

app.run(foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="foo">
  <select ng-include="'listContent'"></select>
</div>
```

**References**

- [Using a toJSON Method with JSON.stringify](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/tojson.php)
- [.toJSON() | Sails.js Documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json)
- [What you didn’t know about JSON.Stringify | CodeKraft](https://abdulapopoola.com/2017/02/27/what-you-didnt-know-about-json-stringify/)
- [TypeScript: Working with JSON · Choly's Blog](http://choly.ca/post/typescript-json/)

Comment: I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do, but it doesn't really seem like it applies to the question.  it seems to only create options for `number` elements, and not create options for `string` elements, which doesn't really solve the question.  The question was how to only show a "default" option when the `ng-model` has no value.

Comment: This is just a way to `Conditionally including select options in angular` as per the title. Since your specific issue was addressed by upgrading, I did not address that here.

Comment: it wasn't *my* issue; it just feels like this answer is really disconnected from the question body, and an odd addition to a question that is 4 years old.